# Derivative of a function wrt a scalar

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be a function from $m \times n$ matrices to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\alpha$ be scalar.
How should I compute the derivative of $f$ wrt to $\alpha$?
$$\frac{d f(\alpha X)}{d \alpha}=?$$

where $X$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.
I believe the dimension of derivative should be the same as dimension of the variable, which means derivative should be scalar as well, but applying chain rule gives me wrong dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I was missing is a dot product,

$$\frac{d f(\alpha X)}{d \alpha}=\langle G, X \rangle$$.

Answer (score 0):

The chain rule works.

Let $\phi(\alpha) = \alpha X$, then
$(D (f \circ \phi) (\alpha))(h) = Df(\phi(\alpha)) (D \phi(\alpha)(h))$.

Since $\phi$ is linear, $D \phi(\alpha)(h) = \phi(h) = h X$, and so 
$(D (f \circ \phi) (\alpha))(h) = h Df(\alpha X) (X)$.

(Keep in mind that $Df(\alpha X): \mathbb{R}^{m \times n } \to \mathbb{R}$, 
so $Df(\alpha X) (X)$ is not just matrix multiplication.)

Comment: Did you mean $D \phi(\alpha)= X$?

Comment: Is the final solution a scalar now?

Comment: Yes. $Df(\alpha X): \mathbb{R}^{m \times n } \to \mathbb{R}$, and $\alpha$ is a scalar.

Comment: I am still confused.  Let $Y =\phi(\alpha)= \alpha X$, then  gradient of $f(.)$ wrt $Y$ (by def of gradient) is a matrix the same size of $Y$. Let's call this matrix $G$. Next, $\frac{d \alpha X}{d \alpha}=X$, which is again a matrix. So the final multiplication is matrix $\times$ matrix, which is not scalar.  I.e. $$\frac{d f(\alpha X)}{d \alpha}= G X.$$What am I missing?

Comment: (I am missing a transpose on $G$.)

Comment: If you have a differentiable function $f:A\to B$ (on suitable spaces, of course), then the derivative at a point $a \in A$ is a mapping of the form $Df(a):A \to B$. In the above, $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \to \mathbb{R}$. So, $D\phi(\alpha): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, and $Df(X): \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \to \mathbb{R}$. Hence $D(f \circ \phi)(\alpha): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oops, I had a small mistake in my answer above which I have corrected.